# this complex matrix is a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, vector-spaces

$V = M_{2}(\mathbb{C})$, $K = \mathbb{C}$ and

$$ S = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} \end{pmatrix} \in V : a_{ij} = \overline{a_{ji}}\text{ for } i, j = 1, 2 \right\} .$$

*I'd like to understand better how to work with complex and matrix to check this question.
I know there are 3 rules, but id like how to apply in cases like that. Thanks in advance, ill be glad for explanations. What is more important to me its to know what to do before check the 3 proprieties, but tips for the whole exercise are also welcome*

Comment: $$A=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}\in S$$But $iA\not\in S$.

Comment: Could you explain?